# Upload multiple image for posts in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel

I want to know how can I have multiple image in my posts?

Currently I have `ImageController` which I tried to get images and attach to `post_id` but the issue of that is if I use that method because I still didn't save my post there will be no id to be attached to images.

Any idea on that?

**Please take a look for better understanding:**

https://ibb.co/huC1Qw

blade:

```
<form action="upload" id="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"><input type="file" class="form-control" name="files[]" multiple></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Upload now"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

controller:

```
public function upload(Request $request) {
  $files = $request->file('file');

  if (!empty($files)):
    foreach($files as $file):
      Storage::put($file->getClientOriginalName(), file_get_contents($file));
    endforeach
  endif;

  return \response::json(array('success' => true));
}
```

route:

```
Route::post('/upload', 'ImageController@upload');
```

Comment: Please share the code you wrote. No images or links to another pages

Comment: @EduardoPacios updated

Comment: Much better. Your input is named files[], why does your loop do '$request->photos as $photo'?

Comment: Seems you are attaching photos to a product. Where does 'post' appear?

Comment: @EduardoPacios sorry since i published this question I tested other methods (result still the same) that's why is different naming, you don't pay attention to that please, if you can give me your solution. thanks.

Comment: @EduardoPacios i will use this method for posts and products both once i get it to work, so really don't matter if you give me your solution base on posts or products. (it's just different naming)

Answer (score 2):

**Approach 1.**
Return `$request->photos` or put them in the session while you are not done yet with post submitting. After it was submitted assign references.

**Approach 2.**
First, save them in [temp] then move and assign to the post.

**Approach 3.**
Create a default record in your database, assign images to that record, get the record_id `post_id` and return to the form that `post_id`. Then just populate that post with your post_id.

**Approach 4.**
It is not the good choice to save images in the database, just save them as file and place de reference link in the database, or find them by the id of the folder that has the same id as your post, or beautify links to them ... definitely not by saving them to database. It is my opinion, everyone has to find his/her way for an easy living.

Comment: thanks for ideas, would you help me with approach 1? seems interesting to me.

Comment: Try after your Product::create...; to Redirect::to("your/last/path")->withInput(); or Input::flash(); and get your aploaded photo back to inputs {{ old('input[name][]') }} just play a little with object in template and you'll find a way

Comment: or after you saved the images return the created object to view with list of images and ids than reference that ids to your post on save.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
use App\ProductsPhoto; \\ add in top of controller
public function upload(Request $request) {
$product = Product::create($request->all());
if ($request->hasFile('files')) {
    $files = $request->file('files');
    foreach($files as $file){
        $productsPhotos = new ProductsPhoto;
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = str_random(5)."-".date('his')."-".str_random(3).".".$extension;
        $destinationPath = 'images/ProductsPhotos'.'/';
        $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
        $productsPhotos->product_id = $product->id,
        $productsPhotos->filename = $fileName;
        $productsPhotos->save();
    }
}
return 'Upload successful!';
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: i get this error `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message` Also I updated my question with current function.

Answer (score 0):

For upload and display images
if you are using two tables.

upload.blade.php

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('/uploads') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <input type="file" id="file" name="files[]" class="inputfile" value="{{ old('arquivo') }}" multiple />
```

Controller

```
public function show() {

      $images = DB::select('SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.id_file');

      return view('index')->with('images', $images);

    }

public function upload(yourRequest $request) {

     $images = model1::create($request->all());
     foreach ($request->files as $file) {
       $filename = $file->store('/uploads');
       modelFiles::create([
         'id_file' => $images->id,
         'file' => $filename
       ]);
     }

     return redirect()->action('Controller@show')->withInput(Request::only('name'));
    }
```

index.blade.php

```
@foreach($images  as $i)
    <div class="item {{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}">
      <img src="{{ asset("storage/$i->file") }}" alt="...">
    </div>
      @endforeach
```